# How to pass a modified sortable list from html to another html?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am writing web application by Flask. I made a sortable list in HTML using `jquery-sortable.js`. I want to pass the new sequences of the list after making modification from one HTML to another HTML.

I have tried to use GET/POST methods. However, it didn't work. Nothing was passed to another HTML.

home.html

```
<script>
...
    $('#sortedList').val(sorted_list);
...
</script>

<form action="http://localhost:5000/about" method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
        {{ form.sortedList.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {{ form.sortedList(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn_outline-info") }}
    </div>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SortedForm(FlaskForm):
sortedList = StringField('Sorted List', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

main.py

```
@app.route("/about", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def about():
    form = SortedForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Sorted list passed {form.sortedList.data}~', 'success')
    return render_template('about.html', title='About', form=form)
```

about.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{ form.sortedList.data }}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: There is no code here that grabs the current sort order from the HTML and posts to the backend.

Comment: I could get the sorted list by `$("ol.list-group-sortable").sortable("serialize").get().join("\n")`. However, I'm very confusing of how to pass the variable to another html. Should I do it in Form GET/POST or by localStorage.

Comment: You may need to send your sorted array from Javascript using AJAX instead of normal form submission.

Comment: I’d use session storage

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I found a way to pass the sorted list by mean of WTForms in Flask in form of a string. The code is updated.